# Why are there so many SMALL files when saving the results to Google Drive?

Tags: google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, export

I have a piece of code:

```
var grid = ee.FeatureCollection("users/quangig/kt2"),
    rgbVis = {"min":0,"max":0.3,"bands":["B4","B3","B2"]};

function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
// Bits 10 and 11 are clouads and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
// Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0)
            .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
   return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
}

var col = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
           .filterDate('2016-01-01','2020-12-31')
           //.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20))
           .filterBounds(grid)
           .map(maskS2clouds)
           //.selct('vis-red', 'vis-green', 'vis-blue')
           .median();

Map.addLayer(col, rgbVis, 'Mosaic');
Map.addLayer(grid, {}, 'Grid');
Map.centerObject(grid, 8);

var seq = ee.List.sequence(1, ee.Number(grid.size()));
print(seq);

var split = seq.map(function(x){
   var fil = grid.filterMetadata('grid', 'equals', x);
   var sCol = col.clip(fil);
   return sCol.visualize(rgbVis)
              .set('grid', x);
});

var final_col = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(split);
print(final_col);

Map.addLayer(final_col.first());

for(var a = 1; a < final_col.size().getInfo() + 1; a++){
 // print(a);
 print(final_col.filterMetadata('grid', 'equals', a).mosaic())
  Export.image.toDrive({
  image: final_col.filterMetadata('grid', 'equals', a).mosaic().select(['vis-red', 'vis-green', 'vis-blue']),
  description:'Image'+'_'+a,
  folder: 'GEE/GRID',
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels:1e13,
  });
}
```

[image]

After clicking download Google Drive, there are many small files. Why are there so many small files? How can there be only 1 file when exporting to Google Drive?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That's EE tiling them for you, so you don't have to work with too large files. You can control this tile size with the `fileDimensions` property in `Export.image.toDrive()`. Specify it big enough to fit the image you're exporting and you'll only get a single file.

From the docs:

> **fileDimensions (List|Number, optional)**:
>
> The dimensions in pixels of each image file, if the image is too large
> to fit in a single file. May specify a single number to indicate a
> square shape, or an array of two dimensions to indicate
> (width,height). Note that the image will still be clipped to the
> overall image dimensions. Must be a multiple of shardSize.